# Constaint on te() tensor product gam mgcv

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, tensor

In the mgcv package in R, I'm working on models whose covariates are forced to change shape at the median (=0). These are the models:

```
gam1 <- gam(Y~ s(X1, pc=0)+s(X2, pc=0), data=data)
gam2 <- gam(Y~ te(X1, X2, pc=c(0,0)),data=data)
```

Unfortunately, the constraint on the `gam2` model with tensor products doesn't work and I don't understand the R error message I get either:

```
Erreur dans if (length(pc) < d) stop("supply a value for each variable for a point constraint") : 
  la condition est de longueur > 1
```

But when I use isotropic smoothing in another model:

```
gam3 <- gam(Y~ s(X1, X2, pc=c(0,0)),data=data)
```

...the constraint applies perfectly. Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the error is due to the definition of `d`. When you look at the `te` code, `d` is not defined.

So, please use `te(X1, X2, pc=c(0,0), d=2)`, then you will get the results. FYI, I also realized that `te(X1, X2, pc=c(0,0), d=2, k=10)` and `s(X1, X2, pc=c(0,0), k=10)` generate same results. Please confirm my finding. You posted this 7 months ago. Hope you resolve already or this helps you.